# how to show and hide image on full screen with telebot python

Tags: python, tkinter, telebot

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tempfile
import os

root = None
blur_thread = None

def kaburkan(image_path):
    global root
    if root:
        root.after(0, root.destroy)  # Schedule the destruction on the main thread
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    # root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: None)  # Disable close button
    root.mainloop()

def blur_thread_func(image_path):
    kaburkan(image_path)

def unblur():
    global blur_thread
    if blur_thread:
        blur_thread.join()  # Wait for the thread to finish
        blur_thread = None

# ... (the rest of your code)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    global blur_thread
    # ... (your existing code)

    elif text.lower() == "blur":
        screenshot_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png', delete=False)
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        im.save(screenshot_file.name)

        # Start a new thread for kaburkan
        blur_thread = threading.Thread(target=blur_thread_func, args=(screenshot_file.name,))
        blur_thread.start()

        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Blur")

    elif text.lower() == "unblur":
        unblur()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Unblur")
```

error: RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

im try without threading and it can run 1x and error. code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tempfile
import os

root = None

def kaburkan(image_path):
    global root
    if root:
        root.destroy()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    # root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: None)  # Disable close button
    root.mainloop()

def unblur():
    if root:
        root.after(0, root.destroy)

# ... (the rest of your code)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    # ... (your existing code)

    elif text.lower() == "blur":
        screenshot_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png', delete=False)
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        im.save(screenshot_file.name)
        kaburkan(screenshot_file.name)
        screenshot_file.close()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Blur")

    elif text.lower() == "unblur":
        unblur()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Unblur")
```

error:
main thread is not in main loop

Comment: Your post is mostly code, please add more details. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `root.mainloop()` should be at the bottom (at the end of script).